# unable to print from skechers website in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, python-requests, webdriver

It tried but it could not print all names , images , prices from https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/athletic-sneakers/?start=0&sz=168

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd 
import time 
url = 'https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/athletic-sneakers/?start=0&sz=168'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver')
driver.get(url) 
vi = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('col-6 col-sm-4 col-xl-3 mb-2 mb-md-1 mb-lg-4 px-lg-3')
for vit in vi:
    title = video.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class = "link c-product-tile__title"]')[0].text
    image = video.find_elements_by_xpath('tile-image c-product-tile__img')[0].text
    price = video.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[1][@class = "value"]')[0].text
    print(title,image,price)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd 
import time 
url = 'https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/athletic-sneakers/?start=0&sz=168'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
pageSource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')
content= soup.find_all('div',class_='col-6 col-sm-4 col-xl-3 mb-2 mb-md-1 mb-lg-4 px-lg-3') 
skechersshoes=[]
for item in content:
    patitle = item.find('div', class_='pdp-link c-product-tile__title__wrap')
    title =patitle.find('a',class_ ='link c-product-tile__title').text
    gender = item.find('div',class_='c-product-tile__gender').text
    gender= gender[1:-1]
    sprice = item.find('div',class_ ='price')
    sbprice = sprice.find('span',class_ ='sales')
    price = sbprice.find('span',class_= 'value').text
    price= price[1:-1]
    links = item.find('a',{'class': 'link c-product-tile__title'})['href']
    try:
        aexclusive= item.find('div', class_ = 'image-container c-product-tile__image-container')
        exclusive =item.find('span', class_ = 'c-product-tile__badge badge badge-primary').text
    except:
        exclusive=''
    exclusive= exclusive[1:-1]
    try:
       
        color =item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-tile__color-swatches__label').text
    except:
        color=''
    color= color[1:-1]
    try:
       
        promotion =item.find('div', class_ = 'promotion').text.strip()
    except:
        promotion=''
    promotion= promotion[1:-1]
    print(title,gender, price,links,exclusive,color,promotion)
    skechers={
            'productname':title,
            'Gender':gender,
            'product_color':color,
            'product_price': price,
            'promotion': promotion,
            'exclusive': exclusive,
            'links': links,
            
    }
    skechersshoes.append(skechers)
df = pd.DataFrame(skechersshoes)
print(df.head())
df.to_csv('skechers.csv')
```